# Angular service not initialized in lazy loaded component

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have an Angular app that has a component with a table. When I click on the table I want to change views with the router and pass that row to the other component. I'm using a shared injectable service to do this, however my component is lazy loaded so the service is not initialized at startup.

My solution was to create a timeout such that the component and it's service get initialized before I tell the shared service to pass the row that was clicked on. Is this the best solution? Code snippet below.

```
onRowClicked(row: any) {
    // first let's switch to the review application view so the sharedService gets initialized
    this.router.navigate(['review']);

    // give it 100 milliseconds to initialize then pass the selected row to the sharedService
    setTimeout(() =>{
      this.sharedService.change(row); // pass selected item
    }, 100);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the service to be `providedIn: 'root'`, this will ensure all the modules have the same instance of the service!

Please ensure you do not import `SharedService` to any of the providers array in modules or components! because this will create separate instances and your service wont be a single instance.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Also when you navigate, there is a promise that is returned, you can just add the service code in the then block of the promise of `navigate`, this might also help to solve your issue!

```
onRowClicked(row: any) {
    // first let's switch to the review application view so the sharedService gets initialized
    this.router.navigate(['review']).then(() => {
        // give it 100 milliseconds to initialize then pass the selected row to the sharedService
        setTimeout(() =>{
            this.sharedService.change(row); // pass selected item
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your example of returning a promise still requires a timeout. Why? Also my shared service already has `providedIn: 'root'`. How do I access that instance of the service from my component?

Comment: I just keep it for safety, you can remove if needed, if you want to use a service, you need to import on the constructor using `private sharedService: SharedService`, does this help your problem?

Comment: I tried your solution without the timeout and it did not work. I have the sharedService in both component constructors. The SharedService is not contained in any providers array.

Comment: @schase Could you replicate the issue with minimal code in a stackblitz, I need the contents of `change` method and the content of the navigated component, that does not fire!

Comment: I tried but I'm getting an error on stackblitz: Error: NG0908: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pcfzgm?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,tsconfig.json,tsconfig.spec.json,tsconfig.app.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&title=Angular%20Starter

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a BehaviorSubject for this use case. Super basic example given below:

```js
// shared.service.ts

public selectedRow: BehaviorSubject<Row | null> = new BehaviorSubject(null)

// table.component.ts

private sharedService = inject(SharedService)

onRowClicked(row: Row) {
  this.sharedService.selectedRow.next(row);
  this.router.navigate(['review'])  
}

// review.component.ts

private sharedService = inject(SharedService)
public row!: Row | null

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.row = this.sharedService.selectedRow.getValue();
}
```